# Cómo agregar los elementos de un arreglo en otro arreglo usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript-objeto

```
    const auto = { 
       marca: "Ford",
        modelo: 1967,
         interiores: []
    }
    
    const  int = [
       "Piel",
        "Tapiceria color Vino",
         "Tapetes"
    ]
    
    auto.interiores.push(int)
    
    console.log( auto )
```

El resultado arrojado es:

```
{
  marca: 'Ford',
  modelo: 1967,
  interiores: [ [ 'Piel', 'Tapiceria color Vino', 'Tapetes' ] ]
}
```

El resultado requerido es sin los dobles corchetes:

```
{
  marca: 'Ford',
  modelo: 1967,
  interiores: [ 'Piel', 'Tapiceria color Vino', 'Tapetes' ]
}
```

Comment: Bueno.. estas agregando un array a un array.. vos deberias desarmar (o buscar como) meterlo item por item y no el array completo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método push acepta elementos individuales. Por lo que cualquier parametro que indiques, será tratado como un elemento sin importar de que tipo sea (incluyendo los arreglos).

Para indicar que deben agregarse uno a uno de los elementos del arreglo usa el Spread Operator.

Cambiando:

```
auto.interiores.push(int)
```

Por:

```
auto.interiores.push(...int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal como indicas en tu resultado esperado, parece que tan solo quieres asignar ese array a esa propiedad de objeto, y eso puedes hacerlo así:

```
auto.interiores = int
```

Te dejo un snippet de ejemplo:

```js
const auto = {
  marca: "Ford",
  modelo: 1967,
  interiores: []
}

const int = [
  "Piel",
  "Tapiceria color Vino",
  "Tapetes"
]

auto.interiores = int
console.log(auto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de cómo adquieres los datos a introducir, puedes usar la sintaxis de desestructuración y asignar al objeto el  valor mediante variables.

Ejemplo ES6

```
const { interiores: tiposInterores } = auto;
```